# What should be kept in mind when writing a garbage collector?

Tags: design, garbage-collection

I would like to learn the important concepts behind garbage collector design. My priority is conceptual clarity, not runtime efficiency. In particular, I would like to know:

- What data structures are used in a garbage collector?
- How much overhead per object is acceptable?
- What triggers the garbage collection process?
- How "stopping the world" is actually implemented?

Comment: Care to explain the close vote? It seemed to me that this question was more appropriate here than in Stack Overflow, so I asked it here. :-|

Comment: The close vote is for 'request for off site resource' which appears to be appropriate for the question. You aren't asking about a problem but rather for someone to provide you with something (a link to a project, book).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) wikipage then the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/). Perhaps also the old [P.Wilson uniprocessor GC survey](http://3e8.org/pub/pdf-t1/gcsurvey.pdf)

I'm not sure that your question makes a lot of sense. In practice, a GC is *tightly* related to the language implementation (or the bytecode virtual machine) it is targeting. Real world GC for compiled languages require deep cooperation between compiler and GC.

Some few GCs are conservative, they suppose that everything which looks like a pointer may be a GC-ed pointer. A typical example is [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), but its implementation is tricky. I believe that coding conservative GCs is practically quite tricky (you need to deeply understand how the address space is managed on your computer).

Most GC are precise, they need to know exactly all the pointers (to GC-ed values) on the call stack. This is often language specific. You could have C++ classes or C macros for that, like in my [qish](http://www.starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html) GC (which is a generational copying GC).

---

I would study several toy Scheme implementations, they usually have a GC.

#### your questions

> What data structures are used in a garbage collector?

I'm not sure it is relevant. You just need to be able to traverse the pointers for local variables (on some call stack, either the machine call stack or more frequently your interpreter's call stack), and you need to scan every pointer in your values (or GC-ed objects). Of course, your GC-ed object may have some (language specific) data structure. And some GCs have complex data structures for efficiency reasons (answering *quickly* to the two main questions: what are the local pointers in this call frame? what are the pointers in this object or GC-ed value).

> How much overhead per object is acceptable?

Define what you mean by overhead. Some GC-s don't have *per object* overhead (especially because the language may bring its own overhead -i.e. metadata, class pointer, vtable- which can partly be reused by the GC). They can have a system-wide overhead (e.g. naive copying GC are using only half of the memory).

> What triggers the garbage collection process?

It depends. Usually the object allocator could trigger GC, e.g. get some memory and if none is available, do a GC.

> How "stopping the world" is actually implemented.

"Stop the world" is a property of GCs (the simplest ones, which complete the GC while application code -a.k.a. mutator- is stopped).

#### missing questions

You forgot several questions.

- What is a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), and why functional languages want a GC? Read also about [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)....
- How to make a multi-threaded friendly GC?

These questions are documented.

Notice that GC are conceptually easy (they are just scanning entirely a graph of references). A naive mark-and-sweep GC for a language whose implementation you know intimately (e.g. that you are implementing right now) is very easy to code (a few dozens or hundreds of lines). What is hard is to debug them and to implement efficient GCs.

A mark&sweep GC is conceptually very easy:

- keep a mark flag or bit in every GC-ed value; allocate values with the mark bit cleared
- be able to iterate on *every* values (even the dead ones). You could e.g. allocate fixed-size values in a big array, or manage a linked list or a vector of (pointers, internal to the GC, to) them.
- code a recursive marking routine (which avoid marking twice by skipping already marked values)
- mark all the local and global variables, and recur the marking routine (mark phase)
- delete every non-marked value (sweep phase)

Copying (notably generational copying) or compacting GC are a bit more complex. You'll probably need to understand what is a write barrier and you'll need to implement it.

Debugging a GC could be painful. With a recent `gdb`, you could use watchpoints and script the debugger in Python.

#### practical advice

Code a tiny interpreter (e.g. of some tiny Lisp, or some language with closures or objects) and code the GC at the same time, while reading some GC books.

Comment: Oh, I already know what a closure is. (A pair of an environment and a function pointer.) That is why I didn't ask that. And how to make a multi-threaded-friendly GC is (not yet) in scope. Right now I want the simplest thing that could possibly work.

Comment: Simplest GC that work for *which language implementation* or which *VM* ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think he just wants to see a minimal working example of a GC for a hypothetical language that does nothing more than say "give me `n` bytes". [Cheney's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm) comes to mind since it's fairly simple (just follow the pointers, copy the objects and leave behind a forward-reference) and requires no data structures. Of course the simplest collector is one that doesn't collect at all.

Comment: No, I feel that Cheney's algorithm is tricky. A simple mark-and-sweep is much easier!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: As Doval said, I want a GC that doesn't assume much about the language I'm implementing. I know that some language implementations use a "uniform representation", where the size of everything is one word, and the first or last bit is used to determine whether the word is a pointer. This is acceptable to me. Also, I should've been explicit w.r.t. how much complexity I can accept: I want a compacting GC. If I didn't, as you said, a simple mark-and-sweep would be easy.

Comment: You cannot have a compacting GC without assumption on the language or the VM. This is simply incompatible (learn what write barrier means in GC context).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch do you think you could do a bit of a transformation on the question so that its a good one that could be reopened (and your content remain on the site - might take a little bit of tweaking to match the transformed question)?  As it is, as it is, the question is rather sub-par, is awkward to find, and really isn't an example of a good question on the site.

Comment: I made an attempt to salvage the question, it still needs work, but I really wanted to edit the last [tag:examples] question out of existence. I echo @MichaelT's request to revise it further into a reopenable question. Thanks for your great answer!